# Create Azure Batch activity in Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I want to create an Azure Batch Activity in my Data Factory Pipe, I set up a trigger that checks for new "last modified" blobs in the last 24 hrs.
As I'm dealing with big files I want to leverage the power of Azure Batch and multiprocess 2 blobs at a time in the same machine.
This is the pipe I've done so far:
[image]
The second activity manipulate the output of the previous one by creating a list variable of {container name}/{blob}.
How can I divide my blob addresses in little batches so that I can feed them to the next batch activity?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The 'ForEach' activity by default runs in parallel so it will spin up at least 20 threads by default and up to 50 depending on your input process.  Make sure the 'Sequential' box on your ForEach is **unchecked**:

[image: ForEach in parallel mode]

If you need to group up into larger groups eg 3 per batch, 5 per batch then that could be a bit more tricky and I would be looking eg a Stored Proc activity, a Databricks notebook or a Synapse Notebook to do that slightly more complex work for me.

Comment: Ok, so the DB notebook allows you to process the variables within the Az Data factory scope? I'm new to Azure and I'm trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Yes you can pass in parameters to Databricks Notebooks via Azure Data Factory.

Comment: I think I'll be doing everything in an AZ function. A question: How do I build a JSON body including a variable?

Comment: This is a separate question.  I suggest you [follow a few tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=call+azure+function+from+data+factory&rlz=1C1GGRV_enGB773GB773&oq=call+azure+functions+from+data+fa&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i22i30.6757j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on Azure Functions with Data Factory and then post a separate question based on what you've tried, what errors you get etc  I think this question is finished and you should mark one of the answers as helpful if it's been helpful to you.